# How to set image icon and editable color using CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to use icon in my navigation bar for web. How can I resize image icon using CSS? How do I change the icon color based on the title?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="icon icon-home" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="icon icon-favorit" href="#">Favorit</a></li>
    <li><a class="icon icon-news" href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a class="icon icon-events" href="#">Events</a></li>
    <li><a class="icon icon-about" href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li><a class="icon icon-contact" href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is one of my CSS rules, the others are the same.

```
.icon-home {
    content:url(../images/food.png);
}
```

Comment: it's case sensitive, in the markup you use `.icon-home` but in the css def it's `.icon-Home`. is this a typo?

Comment: .icon-home is the name of the class it could be any the important thing is what inside it.

Answer (score 0):

to resize the content you can use:

```
.icon-home{
content: "";
background: url(../images/food.png) no-repeat 0 0;;
height:10px;/*whatever you want*/
width:10px;/*whatever you want*/
background-size:100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the icon color you can use css `filter` property. It provides access to some effects like color shifting, brightness and blur.

Check out [CSS Filter Effects](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html) demo page to see the functionality along with css examples.

You can change your css as follows to turn the icon color to grayscale

```
.icon-home
{
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%); //firefox
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); //chrome
}
```

You can also apply multiple functions like that

```
.icon-home
{
  -webkit-filter: contrast(3) grayscale(0.2) sepia(0.6);
}
```